# System is running VERY HOT with SETI@HOME

Tags: sensors

I'm working on a Macbook Pro (11,3) and for some reason the computer is running very hot and I'm not able to configure SETI@HOME.  The kernel is (4.13.0-21-generic) with a temp of about 147.2 deg f or 64 deg c.  It seems to be a problem with SETI@home (8.05) running in the background.
 even after an un-install of SETI it still shows up in "top"?

Thanks the linux sensors display is awesome! I type "sensors" to get the technical readout of the CPU temp...

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +64.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +64.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +63.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +64.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +64.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +36.2°C  

applesmc-isa-0300
Adapter: ISA adapter
Left side  : 4172 RPM  (min = 2160 RPM, max = 6156 RPM)
Right side : 3866 RPM  (min = 2000 RPM, max = 5700 RPM)
TB0T:         +36.0°C  
TB1T:         +36.0°C  
TB2T:         +34.0°C  
TBXT:         +36.0°C  
TC0E:         +67.5°C  
TC0F:         +70.0°C  
TC0P:         +58.0°C  
TC1C:         +63.0°C  
TC2C:         +62.0°C  
TC3C:         +64.0°C  
TC4C:         +64.0°C  
TCGC:         +64.0°C  
TCSA:         +61.0°C  
TCTD:          -0.2°C  
TCXC:         +64.2°C  
TG0D:         +65.2°C  
TG0P:         +60.5°C  
TG1D:         +71.0°C  
TG1F:         +70.0°C  
TG1d:         +65.0°C  
TH0A:         +39.2°C  
TH0B:         +38.8°C  
TH0F:         -42.2°C  
TH0R:         -41.8°C  
TH0V:         +40.8°C  
TH0a:         +39.2°C  
TH0b:         +38.8°C  
TH0c:        -127.0°C  
TM0P:         +52.0°C  
TM0S:         +51.2°C  
TP0P:         +51.0°C  
TPCD:         +56.0°C  
TW0P:         +47.0°C  
Ta0P:         +45.8°C  
TaSP:         +45.0°C  
Th1H:         +48.8°C  
Th2H:         +57.0°C  
Ts0P:         +35.8°C  
Ts0S:         +43.2°C  
Ts1S:         +43.8°C
```

Whatever SETI at home found it seems to be hot on my computer!  ;)

Comment: What do you mean you aren't able to configure SETI@home?

Comment: I would like to be able to run a command from the command line and pass to seti.  The demon maybe requires a restart.  :)